# Using wp_dropdown_pages with ability to jump to page without submit button

Tags: jquery, forms, wordpress, submit

Im using wp_dropdown_pages as a navigation on a page. The navigation is getting the child pages of its parent. I need to be able to jump to the page I select without the submit button.

Here what I have so far.

```
<form id="form-dropdown" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
                    <?php
                        $children = wp_dropdown_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent. '&echo=0');
                        echo $children;

                    ?>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This, You'll need to alter the line `?cat` to `?page_id`

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select category'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
function onCatChange()
{
    if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 )
    {
        location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
        ?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
--></script>
```